# Use Effect Cleanup issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The following code is used as an offline monitor within a RN app - its basically used to display a warning if connection drops.

```
  export default function InternetCheck() {
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    //Intial status

    NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
      if (state.isInternetReachable == false) {
        setIsConnected(state.isInternetReachable);
      }
    });
    //Internet connection listener
    NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      setIsConnected(state.isInternetReachable);
    });
  }, []);
```

I am receiving the following error in the console -

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

Can anyone please explain how to apply a cleanup function in this scenario please?  I have read through various other questions but cant get my head around the logic approach.

Comment: Seems like a simple cleanup, which, by design, is a function you return from this `useEffect` (yours doesn't return anything). In the returned function you should ...`removeEventListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mutable boolean variable to track whether cleanup has started for your render cycle. If it has, then bail on updating the (no-longer existing) state. Also, be sure to [cleanup the `NetInfo` subscription](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo/tree/52058a1ca08f845fea727cc14da6517685d1f9ec#usage). Here's an example:

```js
export default function InternetCheck () {
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let cleanupStarted = false;

    // Initial status

    NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
      if (state.isInternetReachable == false) {
        if (!cleanupStarted) setIsConnected(state.isInternetReachable);
      }
    });

    // Internet connection listener
    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      if (!cleanupStarted) setIsConnected(state.isInternetReachable);
    });

    return () => {
      cleanupStarted = true;
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you can ended up with multiple event listeners if the effect called multiple time

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74560136/use-effect-cleanup-issue/74560212#comment131613786_74560212) @Dilshan The error in the question is about state updates occurring after unmount.

Comment: Agreed after you edited with `unsubscribe()` :)

Comment: Nice! Normally I'd want to use `AbortController` or similar rather than a simple flag so unmounting can actually cancel the operation, but sadly, it doesn't look like NetInfo.fetch supports cancellation. :-|

Answer (score -1):

Hello you need to add return callback cleanup from your useEffect function
Like This:

```
     export default function InternetCheck() {
      const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);
      const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        //Intial status
    
        NetInfo.fetch().then(state => {
          if (state.isInternetReachable == false) {
            setIsConnected(state.isInternetReachable);
          }
        });
        //Internet connection listener
        NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
          setIsConnected(state.isInternetReachable);
        });
//----> add the removeEventListener 
return ()=>{
NetInfo.removeEventListener(...)
......
}
 }, []);
```